# no additional indentation with if __name__ == "__main__":

Tags: python, program-entry-point, idioms

i know that it is good style to define a main() method for "script-style" python programs so it can optionally be included as a module later on.

so let's assume this code (random snippet):

```
a = 5
if a > 0:
    print a
```

becomes

```
def main():
    a = 5
    if a > 0:
        print a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

causing all my code to be indented one more level.
i try to avoid unnecessary indentation/nesting in my code for maximum clarity, and thus i am wondering if something can be done here, like e.g.

```
if __name__ != "__main__":
    return # just leave this file

a = 5
if a > 0:
    print a
```

but (of course) this triggers:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

is something like this possible? advisable? idiomatic?

Comment: "i try to avoid unnecessary indentation for maximum clarity" - for maximum clarity, you would split up a reasonably large script into functions anyways. Also, you don't _need_ to use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` check at all if all your file should do is behave as a standalone script. Using it in these cases is mostly just to clarify the flow of the script, and prevents unintentional side effects if it should be imported somewhere. You're free not to use it as long as you know what you're doing (e.g. not importing it without thinking of the side effects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not possible, really.

When `__name__` is **not** `'__main__'` your module was imported by another piece of code, as a regular module. You cannot bail out early in that case.

And what's wrong with a **one time** extra indentation level? Just hit tab in the editor, and be done with it? Personally, I find that using a `main()` function documents the intent much better than leaving the code unindented.

Comment: `what's wrong with a one time extra indentation level?` He said it: It's about clarity. keep the indention level low is often a property of high quality code

Comment: @hek2mgl: I find the `main()` function to be much clearer in intent.

Comment: The `main` function (as all other functions) should be small. I don't see the reason why an indentation level for some lines should destroy clarity. Of course if you write hundreds of lines in `main()` it could  get a bit ugly, but this applies for every function–as mentioned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not a python coder. Just wanted to point out that reducing indention *does* matter

Comment: @hek2mgl: In Python, indentation matters a whole lot more than in other languages. I take your point, but this is not one of those places where removing an indentation level adds clarity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know about he syntactical meaning of indention in python code. python enforces rules that should apply to every well written source code, that's nice. I don't meant *this* type of indention. I think I just dropped my comment below the wrong answer to the wrong question at the wrong time... :) however, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do this:

```
if __name__ != "__main__":
    throw TypeError("Attempted to import command-line only script")

# Your code here
```

However, I would advise against this pattern - most of the time it should be pretty obvious that a script is command-line only.  And if someone has a use case for something that you defined in a script they shouldn't have to edit it just to be able to import one function.

Comment: creative answer! but as it requires the exception to be caught when importing it does really simplify the overall situation and certainly is something unexpected. and good code should never surprise.

Answer (score 2):

A function should do one thing and this also applies to `main`. It should do (some) `main` stuff and everything else should be done in functions and classes.

There is absolutely no reason to see this as an "unnecessary indentation"…

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to induce the importer itself to behave differently.  It might be possible, though difficult, but certainly not advisable, as you'd be introducing some very unexpected behavior.

If you really want to avoid the extra indentation, you could, I suppose, implement a 'public' and 'private' module, where the public module branches based on `if __name__ == '__main__'` to load a different private module.  But that seems like a lot of hoops to jump through to avoid a few extra indentations.  In any case, if your `main()` is long enough that the indentation is bugging you, you should probably think about breaking more of it out in to functions in the first place.